# How to print 2 arrays using a forEach loop with some conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have 2 arrays:

1. Courses names [bible, math, english]
2. courses scores [100, 60, 80]

I'm trying like to print them in the DOM with 1 of each array in a single row + color conditions according to their scores.

javascript

```
function paintGrades (gradeArr, coursArr) {

  gradeArr.forEach(function (element) {
      var gradeColor = 'bad';
      if (element.gradeArr >= 80) {
        gradeColor = 'good';
      } else if (element.gradeArr >= 60) {
        gradeColor = 'ok';
      } else if (element.gradeArr === 0) {
        gradeColor = 'normal';
      }

      document.getElementById('grade').innerHTML +=
      "<div class='" + gradeColor + "'>" + element.coursArr + ": " + element.gradeArr + "</div>" + "<hr>";
})
}
```

**My expected result should be:**

```
bible: 100 (colored as good)
math: 60 (colored as ok)
english: 40 (colored as bad)
```

...

Comment: what are the values of the array? And what is your current result?

Comment: courses: [bibile, math, english]
grades: [100, 60, 40]

the current result is a list of:
undefined: undefined
undefined: undefined
undefined: undefined

Comment: You should really use a single dictionary object for this. Any kind of manipulation on the arrays can cause mismatched data if you're using two un-keyed arrays.

Comment: @Poodimizer thank you i will consider that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the arrays have the same length (use error checking the handle the case where they aren't), you can use one `for` loop to iterate through both of them.

```
function paintGrades (gradeArr, coursArr) {

  // check that gradeArr.length === courseArr.length

  for(let i=0; i<gradeArr.length; i++){
    let grade = gradeArr[i];
    let course = coursArr[i];

    // do stuff
  }
```